# Creating a 2d sprite with saved image in assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in my assets a folder resources and inside an image pig.png, I want to create a sprite from code with this image, Here is my code:

```
   var filePath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/pig.png";
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
                    tex.LoadImage(bytes);
                    Sprite sp = new Sprite();
                    sp = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f),40);
                }
```

The code runs when I click a button inside a gui, What's wrong?

Fixed code:

```
        Texture2D tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("pig") as Texture2D;
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        GameObject newSprite = new GameObject();
        newSprite.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SpriteRenderer SR = newSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SR.sprite = sprite;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pig image is in the `Assets/Resources` folder, then you have to load the image with `Resources.Load` function not with `File.ReadAllBytes`.

```
//Assign Sprite from Editor. (Where to display the loaded image sprite)
public Image displaySprite;

void loadImage()
{
    //Load Image
    Texture2D tex = Resources.Load("pig", typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
    if (tex != null)
    {
        //Create new Sprite from the Loaded Sprite
        Sprite sp = new Sprite();
        sp = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 40);
        Debug.Log("Not Null");

        //Show Image to screen
        displaySprite.sprite = sp;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Null");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added my final code, it works. thanks :)